# Image provider in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core based web-API called "storage" written using `C#`. This app is designed to serve many web-apps with images. Using other apps I have can request images from the storage using an HTTP request.

To interact with my storage app from a secondary/consuming app, I created a custom file-provider implementation that would allow me to access these images like so

```
public class MyCustomImagesProvider : IFileProvider
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory ClientFactory;

    public MyCustomImagesProvider(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        ClientFactory = clientFactory;
    }

    public IFileInfo GetFileInfo(string subpath)
    {
        try
        {
            var client = ClientFactory.CreateClient("client-name");

            Uri url = new Uri("https://storage.mydomain.com", $"api/files/get?name={subpath}");

            var result = client.GetAsync(url).Result;

            result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(subpath);
            DateTime lastModifiedAt = (result.Content.Headers.LastModified?.DateTime) ?? DateTime.Now;
            var stream = result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;

            return new MyCustomFileInfo(stream, filename, lastModifiedAt);
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        return new MyCustomFileInfo
        {
            Exists = false
        };
    }

    public IDirectoryContents GetDirectoryContents(string subpath) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public IChangeToken Watch(string filter) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Some of my apps require only the thumbnail of the image where others require a full-size and/or thumbnail of the image. Later, I may even need a mid-size image too for some apps (possibly 4 different sizes of the same image.) Diskspace limitation is becoming an issue since I am having to duplicate the same image into multiple files (one for each size) to accommodate all of my apps.

In other words, if I have a file called "abc_fullsize.jpg" then I would need to create and store "abc_thumbnail.jpg", and "abc_midside.jpg" which requires lots of disk space.

**Question**

Would it be efficient to create these images on the fly instead of having to create them on the desk?

I am thinking I would have a `ThumbnailImageProvider`, `MidsizeImageProvider` and `FullsizeImageProvider` each would send required max-size for the storage app and the storage app would read the full-size image from the desk and then respond with the resized image. Here would be an example of the `ThumbnailImageProvider`

```
public class ThumbnailImageProvider : IFileProvider
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory ClientFactory;

    public ThumbnailImageProvider(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        ClientFactory = clientFactory;
    }

    public IFileInfo GetFileInfo(string subpath)
    {
        try
        {
            var client = ClientFactory.CreateClient("client-name");
            // Note the max-width=250 parameter here would tell the API that I need this image recreated on the fly with max width of 250.
            Uri url = new Uri("https://storage.mydomain.com", $"api/files/get?name={subpath}&maxWidth=250");

            var result = client.GetAsync(url).Result;

            result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(subpath);
            DateTime lastModifiedAt = (result.Content.Headers.LastModified?.DateTime) ?? DateTime.Now;
            var stream = result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;

            return new MyCustomFileInfo(stream, filename, lastModifiedAt);
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        return new MyCustomFileInfo
        {
            Exists = false
        };
    }

    public IDirectoryContents GetDirectoryContents(string subpath) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public IChangeToken Watch(string filter) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

The action method on the `api/files/get` endpoint will respond with the following action

```
[HttpGet("get")]
public IActionResult Get(string name, int? maxWidth)
{
    IFileInfo fileInfo = FileProvider.GetFileInfo(name);

    if (!fileInfo.Exists)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    if(maxWidth.HasValue && maxWidth > 1)
    {
        Image image = ImageProcessor.GetResizedImage(fileInfo.CreateReadStream(), maxWidth.Value, out ImageFormat imageFormat);

        using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        image.Save(memoryStream, imageFormat);

        string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileInfo.Name);
        string rawFilename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileInfo.Name);

        string filename = $"{rawFilename}-{maxWidth}{extension}";

        return File(memoryStream, "image/jpeg", filename, fileInfo.LastModified, null);
    }

    return File(fileInfo.CreateReadStream(), "image/jpeg", fileInfo.Name, fileInfo.LastModified, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think that you would be better off applying your logic to a middleware. Have a look at how aspnet's static file middle ware works:

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/19d2f6124f5d04859e350d1f5a01e994e14ef1ce/src/Middleware/StaticFiles/src/StaticFileMiddleware.cs

There are two concerns with your approach:

1. IFileProvider does not support async. You are making network
   calls which a prime candidate for async
2. Resizing images costs a
   fair amount of cpu. A big site with like 300.000 articles (and about
   the same amount of pictures) needed a couple of days of high cpu
   with two 4-core web servers before caching everything to disk.

So my recommendation would be to cache images on disk (or the blob storage while using output cache) -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/middleware?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Regarding (1), I am not sure why `IFileProvider` does not support async. But part of me is thinking that it may not be needed here as each HTTP request would be evaluated in parallel so it won't be blocking the main thread... nothing the less I could be wrong here. In regard to (2), all of my apps are going to be image-heavy. so each page-load could have 20-50 HTTP request for thumbnails. The storage app is running on a 5-core VPS with SSD and 10GB of RAM. Are you recommending to use `app.UseResponseCaching()` to reduce the number of images my server has to resize but dynamic images are good?

Comment: Resizing on the fly is good as long as you can cache it. Easiest is to use response caching, but the drawback is that I your app gets restarted your cache is lost. So disk caching is more robust. Combination of both is good to be able to handle a lot of requests.